# How to listen to events or data change in parent widget and propagate it to child widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, statefulwidget

Let's say I have two stateful widgets "Parent" and "Child", each written in separate class. The Child has functions and callbacks to pass data to Parent. However if something happens in Parent widget, let's say user taps on a button in Parent widget, or some process completes etc., I need to update Child likewise, and maybe, let's say change the background color based on that event which happened in Parent.
How to achieve this in flutter?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can't you just pass the color to the `ChildWidget` as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

A state management framework solves two problems:

1. allowing data to be accessible from non-hierarchical elements in the widget tree
2. being notified when data changes in order to trigger a rebuild with new values

There are many players in this space.  The most common one is probably Provider.  My personal preference is RiverPod.  But use what you're comfortable with.

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options for more details.